# Implementing the Binary GCD algorithm in Mathematica

Tags: code-review, number-theory, number-representation, binary, big-numbers

Well, I have $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and I want to transform $n$ to a binary number which can be done using `FromDigits[IntegerDigits[n, 2]]`. I want to compute the following:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a = IntegerDigits[n,2];
GCD[FromDigits[a],FromDigits[Reverse[a]]]
```

But this becomes very slow when computing very big numbers (like $n=10^{15}$). Is there a way to implement the [Binary GCD algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm). To make a very fast algorithm to compute the desired $\gcd$?

Thanks for any help and/or advice.

Comment: I don't know which version you have but on v13.0, I test your code for numbers around `10^35` and the calculation takes less than `0.00001` seconds.

Comment: @BenIzd I use version 12. But I mean when I used the code from above in a While loop or when producing a table of the results the code takes longer to run.

Comment: On my 4Ghz machine, took 0.02 seconds to compute a table of 1500 values with 1<n<10^50

Comment: @josh can you show the code that you used? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Jan:  AbsoluteTiming[
 myTable = Table[
    theN = RandomInteger[{1, 10^50}];
    a = IntegerDigits[theN, 2];
    GCD[FromDigits[a], FromDigits[Reverse[a]]],
    {i, 1, 1500}];
 ] (* 0.0207 *)

Comment: @josh can you take a look at my second question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/260949/parallelization-in-while-loop-when-testing-if-a-condition-is-met

Comment: @jan:  looked at it briefly:  you seem to be using n in the definition of "a" before defining what n is.

Comment: I think you are confusing things. The numbers you form are base 10 values that happen to have only zeros and ones as digits. The binary GCD algorithm works on any numbers, by operating on their binary digit lists. It does not care what the numbers look like in base 10. You might think there is a speed gain if digits represent powers of 10 instead of 2, but this will be difficult to realize in practice. Especially since binary GCD is probably already what is used by GCD under the hood for integers in the range in question. This is a carefully coded C implementation and will be hard to beat.