# Parallelization in While[] loop when testing if a condition is met

Tags: parallelization, code-review, number-theory, procedural-programming, big-numbers

Well, I am trying to run the following code:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
k = 47;
x = ToString[Sum[1*10^n, {n, 0, k - 1}]];
n = FromDigits[x, 2];
a = IntegerDigits[n, 2];
Monitor[Parallelize[
  While[True, 
   If[GCD[FromDigits[a], FromDigits[Reverse[a]]] == k && 
     Total[a] == k, Break[]]; n++]; n], n]
```

Which runs in a `While[]` loop and tests whenever `GCD[FromDigits[a], FromDigits[Reverse[a]]] == k` and `Total[a] == k` rerturn `True`.

Is there a way to speed up this calculation using parallelization?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: re: visually see the value of `n`: the simplest way is just to add a `Dynamic[n]` and watch the number.

Comment: @CarlLange Found it and edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Ah, indeed, `Monitor` is a simpler way!

Comment: @CarlLange Yes, but this does not help me speeding up the calculation.

Comment: As written, looks like you're using n before defining it:  you define "a" as a function of "n" but you don't define what "n" is until further in the code sequence.

Comment: @josh I edited my code, thanks for the hint.

Comment: `x = FromDigits[Table[1, {47}], 2] // RepeatedTiming` Compare to current method: `k = 47;
x = ToString[Sum[1*10^n, {n, 0, k - 1}]] // RepeatedTiming` compare with `y = FromDigits[ConstantArray[1, 47], 2] // RepeatedTiming` which is even better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on what I understand, you're looking for numbers whose number of 1 bit in its binary format is `47` and `GCD` of the `FromDigits` of the binary, and its reversed should be 47

Populate the possible answers by creating a list by repeating 1, 47 times and then add 0 to different parts of it. (sum will remain `47` but `GCD` should be checked)

Define a test function:

```
ClearAll[test];
test[l_] := GCD[FromDigits[l], FromDigits[Reverse[l]]] === 47
```

I used `Permutations` to find all the cases `0` could be inserted in the list and went as far as inserting 4 zero (you could go further but computation gets heavier).

```
Select[Join[
  Permutations[Join[ConstantArray[1, 47], {0}]],
  Permutations[Join[ConstantArray[1, 47], {0, 0}]],
  Permutations[Join[ConstantArray[1, 47], {0, 0, 0}]],
  Permutations[Join[ConstantArray[1, 47], {0, 0, 0, 0}]]
  ], test]

(* Out: {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},

 {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},

 ... } *)
```

90 different combinations will be returned in less than 2 seconds.

Also, you could use a refined version of the code:

```
Select[Catenate@
  Table[Permutations[
    Join[ConstantArray[1, 47], ConstantArray[0, i]]], {i, 1, 4}], test]
```